# Loading data from DB for caching using ehcache and spring to override exisitng caching mechanism

Tags: java, spring, performance, caching, ehcache

I am working on performance improvement of my project (Spring Project,I don't have much experience in spring, around 7 months!), where we found that most of the memory is being utilized while caching. After a few R&D, I found that Ehcache might help me. In my project we have used static HashMap to load the data from DB on the server start and we are using this map throughout the application. I did see a few example of Ecache and Spring (NOT spring boot) but I am unable to understand how do I replace it with my existing code where there are HashMaps everywhere? Also if there is any other advice or suggestion, please post it..I will be of great help..!  there are a few links on stackoverflow about same question, but they don't have answers for them.. Please help..!

Comment: "HashMaps everywhere"?  They ought to be in one spot - an aspect.  That's a big part of your problem.  Nothing can help you with consolidating them into one.  Just get a shovel and start digging.

Comment: from 'Everywhere'  I ment, for all such database tables where I am caching the data. but there are just 2 places which are eating a lot of memory due to huge data size. :)

Comment: Caching, logging, and transactions are what aspect oriented programming was born for.  Switching from HashMaps that you rolled yourself to EhCache or any other technology won't make those huge entries any smaller.  You'll have the same problem with EhCache.  Reconsider whether you should be caching such large objects.   How often are they used?   You'll have to make the classic time/space tradeoff.  You cache to save time if you have sufficient space; you spend time if you don't.    Your problem isn't technology.

Comment: Thank You @duffymo, for the advice, I would like to add to the info to get more on your thoughts for the same. The data is real large around 60K to 70K and it is to be used through out the application's life cycle. After reading about ehcache, It seems to be promising performance improvement. I referred the article: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-31-caching-and-ehcache

Comment: Go for it.  60-70K doesn't sound big to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data in a HashMap and now you want to use a EHCache, the access time for one entry, if this entry is inside the cache already, will be more then 10x higher of what you have now. See "Runtime comparison for hit hits" at [In Process Java Cache Benchmarks](http://cache2k.org/benchmarks.html).

If you want to save on memory, access times will get much higher, since you have to reload data, when it is requested.

If your application operates on the HashMap and does not need any access to the DB after the HashMaps are loaded, you actually have already the perfect custom cache tailored for your application.

Comment: Oh yes, after going through your shared link, I realise it now. But still wanted to test it myself for at least one of my DAO files and get to how its doing. If you can add something to my doubt it will be great.. :)